# How to import in Typescript without module declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, commonjs, typescript1.6

I have a bunch of autogenerated modules that i need to reference from my typescript files.

Eg

```
import test = require('../templates/test')
```

I am generating CommonJS modules with ES5 output.
So I cant use `amd-dependency` (since that works for amd modules only). 
And I also cannot manually declare the module since 1. it is autogenerated and 2. it has a relative path.

Typescript 1.6 currently shows an error saying it 'Cannot find module'. How do i make it suppress this error and import?

Comment: Seems like a pathing issue. If not, can you provide a brief example from the auto generated modules and mention the paths they are saved relevant to the file that uses them?

Comment: it is not a pathing issue. as i described, the issue simply is that a 'typescript' module has not been declared for the above module, which is obvious since it was auto generated. the question asks how to suppress typescript errors for modules without typescript definition.

Answer (score 9):

> How do i make it suppress this error and import

If you are sure that the `require` statement is *valid* and want to switch off any *type checking* on the import, you can just use `node.d.ts` and do:

```
var test = require('../templates/test')
```

ie. just use `var` instead of `import`.

Comment: Sending code love in your direction. I struggled with this for quite some time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use TypeScript imports (which are just ES6 imports), you could use this:

```js
import * as test from '../templates/test';
```

and then call your API like this:

```js
let foo = test.MY_API;
```